# Why do I receive a UnsupportedMediaType message when trying to analyze a form?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using the forms recognizer preview.  I have already trained a model using the documentation provided in this documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/curl-train-extract

However when I attempt to execute the curl command to analyze the request; I get an error message indicating:

{"error":{"code":"UnsupportedMediaType","message":"In case of HTML form data, the multipart request must contain a document with a media type of - 'application/pdf', 'image/jpeg' or 'image/png'."}

The file I am uploading is a PDF (I've verified the response headers).  I have also indicated this in the curl request as:

curl -X POST "https://[omitted]/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models/[omitted]/analyze" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "form=[omitted];type=application/pdf" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: [omitted]"

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your PDF document, The issue may be with the PDF document containing different media types.

Answer (score -1):

Just resolved it. Change the Content-Type to 'application/pdf' and in the body, send through the contents of the PDF, it doesn't seem to work with just the path.